# AppoloStack NetworkInterface AfterWare

Tags: graphql

I have a simple idea to try to do check for different type of errors in `afterware` in NetworkInterface. Let's assume I can't use response.code for that purpose, so I need to access the body:

```
networkInterface.useAfter([{
    applyAfterware({ response }, next) {
        // need to access response.body here
        next();
    }
}]);
```

But it doesn't have `response.body` available to use, so I figured like there should be another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I believe that response object is a [`fetch` response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), and therefore you would do something like:

```js
networkInterface.useAfter([{
    applyAfterware({ response }, next) {
        // Assuming body is a JSON object, see link for other methods
        response.json().then(function(body) {
          // Work with the body here
          next();
        });
    }
}]);
```